# Is it a good idea to have an index when the column value changes several times over record lifetime?

Tags: sql-server, index, update

I have a table where one of the columns represents an object state - let it be `State` of type `int`. The `State` value starts with `1` and changes to `7` with values in between. Over a row lifetime there're maybe three to seven such changes. Meanwhile I have thousands of queries that `SELECT` or `UPDATE` rows with specific `State` values. One rarely run `UPDATE` changes all rows that have `4` to `5`.

I feel like adding an index on `State` column would be a good idea. Yet since `State` can change it means the index will have to be changed on every such change.

Do I add an index or not? How do I make a decision?

Answer (score 3):

If the query against this column is rare, then will you really gain from it? Depending on cardinality, the index might not really help anyway, or even be chosen to satisfy the query. And remember that it has to be maintained 100% of the time.

Comment: I do have `SELECT` against that column - and a lot of them.

Comment: @sharptooth I apologize, I read the "rarely" part and thought that was regarding a SELECT query (I usually see updates called statements, not queries). Still, with a very small range of possible values, it is unlikely that an index will help. But you can always test it!

Comment: How do I make sure there's no serious negative impact from my change?

Comment: @sharptooth test it somewhere other than production?

Comment: That's not really possible because it'd be very hard to simulate exactly the same load patterns.

Comment: @sharptooth so how have you ever tested any changes?

Comment: I usually make changes that are more or less easy to validate in testing environment but this one seems to not be of such kind.

Comment: @sharptooth no, there is a very big difference between testing a change for validity and testing a change for performance. Hardware/load usually have very little bearing on the former, but they certainly matter for the latter.

Comment: I would like to add one more thing. The index on state column might cause page splitting as state value will be changed from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 and so on. This will cause the fragmentation in index.Also, page splitting generates quite large amount( it depends) of log. Also, update wont be direct in place update but rather a delete followed by insert which is costly and it will also cause generation of extra amount of log. Thus before deciding the index consider all these things.If gain in select is more than update overhead than you can go ahead.